# Docker Compose LAMP stack not serving index.php

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I'm doing some freelance work and the people I'm working with use a LAMP stack with docker. I've never used docker before and I am having some issues. They all use Macs, while I have windows so they have not been able to help me. I've been working on this on and off for the last 12 hours and cannot get my index.php page to show up. I'll go over the steps I've taken so far and provide the file structure.

I was working in windows powershell

1. Installed Docker Desktop from [here](https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows)
2. I followed the steps [here](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/#example) to create a new docker-machine

   2a. The command I ran was *'docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "DockerVS" default'*
3. I then ran *'docker-machine env'*
4. Then I ran *'& "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker-machine.exe" env | Invoke-Expression'*
5. Then, while in the same directory, I grabbed the project from GitHub, changed directory into the location with the .env and docker-compose.yml files. then ran the command *'docker-compose up -d'*
6. At this point, I was supposed to be able to run *'docker-machine ip default'*, paste that IP into my browser and see the page. That is what all my coworkers had done with their macs, at least. If it matters, the IP is 10.0.0.117

Now something is definitely running there, it attempts to get the "index.php" file, but it returns "File not found" to the browser. The page is also running phpMyAdmin, so if I type in 10.0.0.117:8080 to the browser, I see [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRmbj.jpg). So I'm confident that I'm on the right track, I just assume I've done something minor.

So the solutions I've attempted. My first guess was that I needed a port similar to :8080 that make the php page pop up. I ran *'docker-compose ps*' and I tried the ports 443, 3360, and 9000 which I all see here: [image]

Naturally no go. Next I tried various paths, and then tried all the aforementioned ports and paths together. The paths I tried were

- /index.php
- /index.html
- /index
- /index.htm
- The above four with /public-html in front
- The above with /LAMPProject in front

The file structure looks like this:
[image]

So all in all, that is what I am working with. It's a fairly simple docker LAMP set up before I start working on bigger stuff. Any advice at all would be very welcome.

Comment: I'm new to docker too, but we use the docker images which combine apache and PHP in one image, e.g. php:7.2.14-apache-stretch from https://hub.docker.com/_/php/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should map your phpmyadmin port to another one like 8081 instead 80, apache container mapped to 80 too.

Comment: I too having the same issue, i can run the files by giving my docker ip address and filename like 192.168.99.100/index.php (it is working fine), but when I copy all the project files to another computer which has docker installed. When i tried to run the files in different computer, it is showing error The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: i think this should be port conflicting problem !